# Unable to send props in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-props

I am trying to send 2 props to my navbar component but it does not receive the data.

**Here is what I get instead of my data:**

[image: one]

#### Code:

**Front.vue** (upper template)

```
<template>
    <front-nav :menus="menus" :settings="settings"></front-nav>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    <front-footer></front-footer>
</template>

<script>
    import frontNav from './frontNavBar.vue';
    import frontFooter from './frontFooter.vue';
    export default {
        name: 'front',
        data(){
            return {
                settings: {
                    name: '',
                    favicon: '',
                    logo: '',
                },
                menus: [],
            }
        },
        components: {
            frontNav,
            frontFooter
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getData();
        },
        methods: {
            getData() {
                axios.get('/api/general')
                .then(response => {
                    this.settings = response.data.settings[0];
                    this.menus = response.data.menus;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('error', error);
                });
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Nabar component** (receiving props)

```
<template>
    <div>data goes here...</div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        name: 'frontNav',
        props: ['settings', 'menus'],
        data() {
            //
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('settings: ', this.settings)
            console.log('menus: ', this.menus)
        },
        methods: {
            //
        }
    }
</script>
```

> results of `console.log('settings: ', this.settings)` and `console.log('menus: ', this.menus)` are in image above.

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

You are mounting `front-nav` before `getData()` runs and returns the appropriate response, hence empty props. You should wait for `getData()` to complete before mounting `front-nav`.

You could do something like:

1. Use [`<Suspense>`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html)
2. Use `<front-nav v-if="menus" :menus="menus" :settings="settings">` or something appropriate that you know will have a value when `getData()` returns a response and you have meaningful value.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Edited my answer to offer more details.

Comment: I've tried both your suggestion, none worked!

Comment: Hmm, could you make sure that my suspicion is correct by `console.log`ging in `then` of axois, comparing which logs first?

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

I've added `childDataLoaded: false,` to my `Front.vue` component and set it as true when data are loaded so it works now, here is how:

```
<template>
    <template v-if="childDataLoaded"> // <-- here
        <front-nav :menus="menus" :settings="settings"></front-nav>
    </template>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    <front-footer></front-footer>
</template>

<script>
    import frontNav from './frontNavBar.vue';
    import frontFooter from './frontFooter.vue';
    export default {
        name: 'front',
        data(){
            return {
                childDataLoaded: false, // <-- here
                settings: {
                    name: '',
                    favicon: '',
                    logo: '',
                },
                menus: [],
            }
        },
        components: {
            frontNav,
            frontFooter
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getData();
        },
        methods: {
            getData() {
                axios.get('/api/general')
                .then(response => {
                    this.settings = response.data.settings[0];
                    this.menus = response.data.menus;
                    this.childDataLoaded: true, // <-- here
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('error', error);
                });
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```